# Watashi versus Wataxi, are they different accents?

Tags: english-to-japanese

I've noticed after watching a lot of anime that sometimes "Watashi wa" sounds like "Wataxi wa" or maybe "Watakshi wa." The instances I've heard the latter were always from females. I was wondering if there's a different accent, dialect, or linguistic custom behind this pronunciation? Thank you.

For example, I heard it at 4 minutes 20 seconds into the video here:

http://gogoanime.io/basilisk-episode-14

(I used the top link). It also happens again at about 4m 38s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are hearing わたくし watakushi, which is like わたし watashi in a humbler manner. Nothing special about it.

Comment: Makes sense! Thank you! Do you happen to also know the difference between tosa and ji juei for father?

Comment: お父さん otohsan is like dad whereas 父上 titiue is more like when you call your own father "father".

Answer (score 2):

Actually Watashi わたし and Watakushi わたくし aren't only for female. Male also use them, especially in serious situation like business or public speech, etc.

You can often hear Watakushi when a politician gives a speech.